# AutoMapper: access destination meta info in v6.x

Tags: c#, automapper

moving from AutoMapper 4 to 6

In the ITypeConverter, how do we access the parent context, so we know what property is being populated, in version 4:

```
context.PropertyMap.DestinationProperty
```

So following was possible:

```
public class UserDetailsConvertor : ITypeConverter<OAuthProfile, UserDetials>
{
    public Dto.Accounts.UserDetials Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var src = context.SourceValue as OAuthProfile;

        if (src == null) return null;

        if (!context.PropertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name.Contains("Internal"))
        {
            return new UserDetials()
            {
                Id = src.Id
            };
        }

        if (src.InternalAccountId.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new UserDetials()
        {
            Id = src.InternalAccountId
        };
    }
}
```

note that the User details is being mapped to 2 properties (Internal and Provider) that is what the above conditional logic was sorting out.

in V6 this is not posisble from what i can see, there is an items collection, but this seems to contain information for the entire mapping (of all objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's all gone. It was very expensive to capture and pass that context everywhere. You might want to look at member resolvers instead.